# Show joined field data in a select option using Symfony form builder

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I am trying to make a form for adding race results to an event, but cant figure out how to display information from joined tables concatenated together in the options of one select box.

Here is my database structure:

Person Table:

```
id | name
----------
1  | fred
2  | dave
3  | james
```

Entrant Table (the code is the entrants race number - the kind of thing you pin to your shirt):

```
id | code | person_id | category_id
---------------------------------
1  | 210  | 1         | 1
2  | 211  | 2         | 1
3  | 212  | 3         | 1
4  | 156  | 1         | 2
6  | 157  | 3         | 2
```

Results Table:

```
id | time | entrant_id
---------------------
1  | 1:20 | 1
2  | 1:35 | 2
3  | 2:02 | 3
```

Desired Output when adding results to Category=1:

```
<select>
    <option>210 - Fred</option>
    <option>211 - Dave</option>
    <option>212 - James</option>
</select>
```

The code I have currently got in my ResultType gets me just the person.name which is a good start (at the expense of 1 extra query per name) but not the entrant.code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('time')
        ->add('entrant', 'entity', array(
            'class'=>'KP\EventsBundle\Entity\Entrant', 
            'property' => 'person.name',
            ));
}
```

How can I get both the entrant.code and the person.name in the same list of options?

I have only been using Symfony for a couple of weeks, so please be gentle with me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I came up with off the top of my head is to implement the `__toString()` method in the `Entrant` class:

```php
public function __toString()
{
    return sprintf("%d %s", $this->code, $this->person->getName());
}
```

Remove the `property` option from `entrant` field of the form type to make it use the method.

To solve the extra queries problem, you could do a [fetch join](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) in the `query_builder` option of the `entity` type.